# I am trying to use my Pi 3 as RADIUS server and TACACS+ server but i dont know how and is it possible?

Tags: raspbian, networking

I am trying to use my Pi 3 as RADIUS server and TACACS+ server because im trying to practice for the CCNA is it possible to configure the pi as a radius or TACACS+

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi is a normal (small) computer running Raspbian what's just Debian compiled for the ARM processor and with some firmware for the RasPi. You find **freeradius** and **tacacs+** in its repository. So just install and run it.

Look at it and install it with:

```
rpi ~$ apt show freeradius
rpi ~$ apt show tacacs+
rpi ~$ sudo apt install freeradius
rpi ~$ sudo apt install tacacs+
```